# Unable to access ~1 TB of my /home partition

Tags: disk-usage

My `/home` partition has 1.6 TB total space. This partition consists of multiple users. Due to lack of space notification, the exploration revealed total files present makeup only 204 GB of data. The free space mentioned is ~ 100 GB. Almost 1 TB of the disk space in that partition is missing.

```
[root@cfdlab home]# df -h --total
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       197G   23G  165G  12% /
devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G   69M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G  3.4G   28G  11% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       1.8T   95G  1.7T   6% /data
/dev/sda7        29G   12G   16G  44% /var
/dev/sda3       1.5T  1.4T   36G  98% /home
/dev/sda2       976M  296M  613M  33% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G   60K  6.3G   1% /run/user/0
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1015
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1012
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1006
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1007
total           3.7T  1.5T  2.0T  44% -
[root@cfdlab home]# du -hs * du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h
du: cannot access ‘du’: No such file or directory
16K lost+found
60K psf
108K    test
208K    praveen
220K    log
77M D
113M    H
127M    cfd
334M    .Trash-0
2.0G    C
5.1G    G
7.9G    F
60G B
60G E
69G A
204G    total
```

EDIT:

> On an extⁿ filesystem, running resize2fs without any argument will
>   expand it to the available space

It is running on ext4 filesystem. However by running, it throws,

```
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
The filesystem is already 401449984 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

By executing

```
[root@cfdlab ~]# du -xhcs /home/* /home/.*
87G /home/A
60G /home/B
2.0G    /home/C
127M    /home/cfd
77M /home/D
19G /home/E
7.9G    /home/F
5.1G    /home/G
113M    /home/H
220K    /home/log
16K /home/lost+found
208K    /home/praveen
60K /home/psf
108K    /home/test
334M    /home/.
23G /home/..
203G    total
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What file system do you use? Maybe for some reason your partition is larger than your file system. Most file systems have an internal size marker that can be different from the available space. On an extⁿ filesystem, running resize2fs without any argument will expand it to the available space.

Comment: Note that your command returns an error. You may want to do `du -xhcs /home/* /home/.*`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lsblk` or perhaps even `lsblk --output "NAME,PATH,SIZE,FSSIZE,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT"`.

Comment: There may be a deleted file, still being opened by a running process. Have you rebooted your system since this problem occurred?

Comment: @Bachsau I have updated the question with the commands you have suggested. Hope the edit is useful to you.

Comment: @Kusalananda Please find the updated question with the output of the command you have suggested.

Comment: @Ned64 lsblk --output PATH throws unknown column path. The system is running on centos 7.4 if that matters.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli The system is a cluster located remotely. We rarely reboot the system. We thought of doing it as a last resort.

Comment: `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'` may help you in locating deleted files...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I got a big list of deleted files. But will it can hold up to 1TB of the space? Only rebooting is the only solution?

Comment: The problem is that there are open processes holding pointers to these deleted files. When those processes quit, the files are expunged, but not before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux and Unix, files might be deleted while they are still being held open by a process. The operating system still keeps track of it, though. To read or write to a file, a process must first ask to open it. It then receives a file descriptor. When it is done with the file, or exits, it should close the file.

If a file is deleted while a process still keeps an open file descriptor, the data is not really freed up before the process exits. This is done to avoid a very dangerous problem: If process A keeps open a file X (for instance a log file), which is then deleted, and then process B asks to write to a new file, it must not be allocated any space occupied by X, or you could suddenly have two processes writing to that same file, and process A could corrupt the file written by process B.

To find the files and process ids, use `lsof | grep '(deleted)'`. The first columns list the process name, process id, and user name of the process. Depending on the nature of the processes with the deleted files, you can decide whether to stop the processes (`kill [pid]`) or if you should instead reboot the system.

If you have processes holding a terabyte of stale data, it sounds like some program is badly malfunctioning. But that of course depends on what you are using this box for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will get back to you once I fix the problem. "Some program is badly malfunctioning"-How can I locate the source? There are multiple users running the different codes on the cluster.

Comment: If the problem is caused by something like this, a reboot is the easiest way to fix it.